# How can I obtain the selected option into a select dropodown tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have the following `select` dropdown:

```
<select id="selTipoRap" class="form-control" th:field="*{tipoRappresentante}" required="required" style="width: 55%;" onChange="nascondiBoxDocumentazione(this);">
    ......................................................................
    ......................................................................
    OPTIONS LIST
    ......................................................................
    ......................................................................
</select>
```

Then I have this JavaScript function that is performed when the user selects an option into the previous select:

```
function nascondiBoxDocumentazione(ruoloSelezionato) {
    alert("NASCONDI");
}
```

How can I obtain the value of the selected option into this JavaScript function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function nascondiBoxDocumentazione(ruoloSelezionato) {
    alert(ruoloSelezionato.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="selTipoRap" class="form-control"  style="width: 55%;" onChange="nascondiBoxDocumentazione(this);">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: inline javascript belongs in history books.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work for you.

```
 $('#selTipoRap').on('change' , function(){
       nascondiBoxDocumentazione($(this).val());
  });
```

for `<select>` usually i always use the **[change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

EDIT: Following a comment from Alexander Solonik, my previous answer was not optimal, this should be much more efficient.

```js
$('#selTipoRap').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selTipoRap">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1 ">One</option>
  <option value="2 ">Two</option>
  <option value="3 ">Three</option>
</select>
```

A pure JavaScript solution:

```js
var selTipoRap = document.getElementById('selTipoRap');

selTipoRap.onchange = function() {
  alert(selTipoRap.value)  
}
```

```html
<select id="selTipoRap">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1 ">One</option>
  <option value="2 ">Two</option>
  <option value="3 ">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: inline javascript belongs in history books.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, you're right. I was attempting to closely replicate the original code, but I've update my answer to be more optimal now.